# how is data saved in azure document db (cosmos DB)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I want to know How is the J-son i am giving the document db saved.

is it compressed, serialized or saved as plain J-son string.

I need to save records in document db where each record consists of 10,000 numbers of 2 bytes each, and i want to know the overhead of the saving.

How is the most efficient way (in memory aspect) to save these numbers in 
J-son ? 
I will always read and write the entire 10,000 of numbers in my requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [capacity planner](https://www.documentdb.com/capacityplanner#) calculator where you can upload your sample file, specify the amount of documents in collection and get an estimate of total collection size.

The collection size is calculated based on raw JSON document, without any compression applied. So it's more or less equivalent to the disk size of the documents on your hard drive.

Cosmos DB will also add some fields like `_ts` to each document + secondary indices, so the total size might be a bit higher.

If you need any compression, you need to do it in your application (e.g. make one JSON encoded binary field which contains compressed array of 10,000 numbers).